# How to migrate OAuth authentication to Azure OpenId Connect authentication in an ASP.NET MVC app on .NET 4.6?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, openid-connect

Currently the configuration of my app looks like this:

```
OAuthOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
        {
            ApplicationCanDisplayErrors = true,                
            AuthorizeEndpointPath = new PathString("/Auth/Authorize"),
            TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/Auth/Token"),
            AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(20),
            AccessTokenProvider = jwtProvider,
            Provider = new ApplicationOAuthProvider(PublicClientId)
        };

BearerOptions = new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType,
            AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Active,
            AccessTokenProvider = jwtProvider
        };
    

app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(OAuthOptions);
app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(BearerOptions);
```

I tried some forums, most of them are for .NET Core, I tried Visual Studio default application with connected services, but didn't achieve my desired result

Comment: pls find the sample you required here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity-platform/sample-v2-code?tabs=apptype#web-applications

Answer (score 0):

*I tried the following code to migrate OAuth authentication to Azure OpenID Connect authentication in an ASP.NET MVC app targeting .NET Framework 4.6:*

**Code :**

***Startup.Auth.cs :***

```cs
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect;
using Owin;
using System;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;

[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(WebApplication59.Startup))]
namespace WebApplication59
{
    public partial class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            ConfigureAuth(app);
        }

        private void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());
            string clientId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:ClientId"];
            string aadInstance = EnsureTrailingSlash(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:AADInstance"]);
            string tenantId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:TenantId"];
            string postLogoutRedirectUri = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:PostLogoutRedirectUri"];

            app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
            {
                ClientId = clientId,
                Authority = $"{aadInstance}{tenantId}",
                RedirectUri = postLogoutRedirectUri,
                PostLogoutRedirectUri = postLogoutRedirectUri,
                ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.IdToken,
                Scope = OpenIdConnectScope.OpenId,
                TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateIssuer = false 
                },
                Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
                {
                    AuthenticationFailed = context =>
                    {
                        return Task.FromResult(0);
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        private static string EnsureTrailingSlash(string value)
        {
            if (value.EndsWith("/"))
            {
                return value;
            }
            return value + "/";
        }
    }
}
```

***Web.config :***

```html
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="ida:ClientId" value="<Clirn_ID>" />
    <add key="ida:AADInstance" value="https://login.microsoftonline.com/" />
    <add key="ida:Domain" value="<Domain_Name>" />
    <add key="ida:TenantId" value="<Tenant_ID>" />
    <add key="ida:PostLogoutRedirectUri" value="https://localhost:<port>/signin-oidc" />
  </appSettings>
```

***index.cshtml :***

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Home Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Welcome!</h2>
</body>
</html>
```

***_Layout.cshtml :***

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET Application</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")

</head>
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-toggleable-sm navbar-dark bg-dark">
        <div class="container">
            @Html.ActionLink("Application name", "Index", "Home", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggler" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target=".navbar-collapse" title="Toggle navigation" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
                    aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse d-sm-inline-flex justify-content-between">
                <ul class="navbar-nav flex-grow-1">
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "nav-link" })</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "nav-link" })</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "nav-link" })</li>
                </ul>
                 @Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="container body-content">
        @RenderBody()
        <hr />
        <footer>
            <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - My ASP.NET Application</p>
        </footer>
    </div>

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

I granted the openid and profile permissions in the app as follows:

[image]

**Output :**

It ran successfully. I clicked on the **Sign in** button as follows:

[image]

It redirected me to choose my account for Sign in as follows:

[image]

I successfully signed in and clicked on the **Sign out** button as follows:

[image]

I selected my account for Sign out as follows:

[image]

I successfully signed out.

[image]